# Mysql not working when used double alias

Tags: mysql

Hey guys am really new to mysql.I have heard of alias in mysql and i have tried double alias with the string like

```
select ('name' as bae,'age' as ages) as person;
```

When i run the above code it doesnt give me the output and raises the error.I dont understand why the double alias didnt works in mysql.

Any help to make this one correct would be really appreciated..Thanx in advance

Comment: What are you trying to get ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? The "double alias" is far from being the only problem in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query are the parentheses.  They represent a single expression and you don't put aliases (or commas usually) inside expressions.  So, this fixes the immediate problem:

```
select 'name' as bae, 'age' as ages
```

I'm not sure what the second "as person" is supposed to be.  Perhaps you want a subquery:

```
select person.*
from (select 'name' as bae, 'age' as ages) person
```

Answer (score 0):

A really basic MySQL query should look something like:

```
SELECT 
    [COLUMN_NAME] AS [ALIAS_NAME]
FROM 
    [TABLE_NAME]
```

Based on your query it appears you are trying to retrieve the two columnns `name` and `age` from the `person` table. 
If this is the case, the following query can help you:

```
SELECT 
    name AS bae,
    age AS ages
FROM 
    person
```

But, this is still just one big guess, if you really want us to help you with your problems, you should give some more information about what you are trying to achieve.